# SQL comparison matching ORDER BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

When one orders results by multiple columns the database has to do something to compare NULL values (e.g. order them first last).  But how can I replicate that same order in a comparison in my query (i.e. I need to compare row A before row B just when A would occur before B in the, fixed, ORDER BY).

For instance, how could one find all rows that occur before row R= (date:  2020-01-01, x: NULL, y: 20) in the ordering ( date DESC, x ASC, y DESC)?  In other words, the query should return the set of elements that would appear *before* R appears in the query "SELECT T.* ORDER BY (T.date DESC, T.x ASC, T.y DESC)

(I mean without expanding out every possible case with IS NULL and IS NOT NULLS)
I'm happy to use postgresql specific features if necessary.

Comment: use nulls last.   Order by T.date desc nulls last, t.x asc nulls last, t.y desc nulls last

Comment: No, the problem is the query should *only* return the rows that occur before R in the ordering.  So I need a comparison statement T.A < T.B that's true just when A occurs before B in the order by (well with T.B  actually constants but same difference).  Apparently, I didn't write it very clearly so I tried to clarity.

Comment: You need to write a WHERE clause that compares the necessary columns in your dataset with the values you want to compare them do - and your WHERE clause needs to cater for nulls

Comment: So nothing short of doing it by cases?  The reason I asked is because the usual < comparisons don't work for NULL in a way that matches the ordering clauses so I was hoping there was an easier way since this seems like a common need.  Of course, I can just divide them into a bunch of cases.

Comment: I obviously know how to actually spell out each case.  Check if it's null

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “doing it by cases” and also your references to ORDER BY seem to be irrelevant, and therefore confusing, to your question. You seem to be asking about values that are greater than/less than other values, in which case the order that records are in is irrelevant (especially as DBMSs have no concept of record order - until you query data). If you don’t want to code for nulls in multiple WHERE clauses you could always use NVL to default any null value to a value that is bigger/smaller than any non-null value in your data

Comment: I mean that if get the results from  date DESC, x DESC, y DESC) (say NULLS FIRST on all of them) then it first gives me all the null dates ordered just by (x ASC, y DESC) etc.  However, if I try to just use the WHERE clause WHERE (T.date, T.x, T.y) < (value_date, value_x, value_y) then I won't get any null dates in my answer.

Comment: So, if I want to match the full ordering, I have to expand it out as WHERE (T.date is NULL OR T.date < value_date) OR (T.date  = value_date AND T.x < value_x) OR .. if value_date isn't NULL but if it is NULL instead do  (WHERE T.date is NULL AND (T.x is NULL OR T.x < value_x) ... (except I also need to the same expansion based on whether value_x is NULL).  I would have thought SQL would have some easy way to do a tuple comparison that returns the same order as the ORDER BY does regarding NULLS

Comment: I realize that they have no concept of order until I query the data the issue is the different way NULL is treated in an ORDER BY clause and in a comparison.  In an ORDER BY NULL is treated as if it was an actual value (NULLS FIRST pretends NULL is the largest value and so if, in the ORDER above NULL, NULL 5 sorts before NULL, NULL, 6) but in a WHERE clause NULLS don't compare so you have to mimic the way ORDER BY does it you to break off the cases where the values in the first, second third etc.. columns are NULL and do them separately.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confusing 2 different concepts and then wondering why things don't work in the way you expect. But continuing this discussion is probably unproductive - it works the way it does and you have to live with it. You have to options for dealing with comparisons when your data contains nulls e.g:

```
WHERE (a.col1 = b.col1 OR (a.col1 IS NULL AND b.col1 IS NULL))

WHERE nvl(a.col1,0) = nvl(b.col1,0)
-- you might need to replace the 0 in the NVL statements with a value that works with you particular data
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to expand out the whole damn thing by cases.  Indeed, since I didn't get a quick answer I've since actually done that.  But mimicing the same order applied by ORDER BY in a comparison (e.g. having some kind of comparison statement on rows which is true just when row A would be returned before row B in a given order by) is quite long and it seems like it's a common need so I thought there might be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Specifically, the whole thing becomes something like:  WHERE ((a.col1 is NULL) OR (a.col1 < value_1))  OR ((a.col1 = value_1) AND  (   ((a.col2 is NULL) OR (a.col2 < value_2)  OR (  (a.col2 = value_2) AND (a.col3 is NULL OR a.col3 < value_3)))).  And that's ignoring the possibility the values themselves are null.  If you consider that possibility it's about 3x longer.  That's pretty complicated for something that's essentially just a tuple comparison and a common need (it's exactly what tuple comparison would give u if NULL was treated as a value).

Comment: But, I see I didn't explain the point very.  I should have said: Is there a shorter way to write a WHERE clause that returns the set of elements which would occur before a given row R under the ORDER BY (col1 ASC, col2 DESC, col3 ASC) where any of those columns may be null.  I had a specific query in mind where I needed to get that set of elements and I still happened to be ordering them in that way but I see that created confusion.  Anyway, I think it's now clear the answer is no, I just have to do it the long way.